# What is the use of "$" keyword in c# - web api

Tags: c#

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/products/{product.Id}", product);
```

In the above code I've been using the $ keyword but I don't the significance of this keyword. I searched in google but coiuldn't find proper answer. I think this might be a duplicate but couldn't find relative answer even in stackexchange.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

It's an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) - the new feature of C# 6, which is basically just a syntax sugar for String.Format (compiler converts interpolated strings into the String.Format calls). Your string is equivalent to

```
String.Format("api/products/{0}", product.Id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$"api/products/{product.Id}"
```

is the short version for

```
string.Format("api/products/{0}", product.Id);
```

You could have a look in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)